# how to filter elements of list of list based on the value of a column in Groovy

Tags: list, groovy

I am working with `Groovy` and have this `list of list` with certain number of elements:

```
def rList = [["Using Patient Feedback","Completed","No Results Available","Condition1","Other","Phase I","18 Years and older   (Adult, Senior)","Other","https://folder1//folder2"],["The Effect of a Education ","Completed","No Results Available","Condition1","Behavioral","Glycemic Control","18 Years and older   (Adult, Senior)","Other","https://folder1//folder3"],["The Public Private Partnership","Completed","No Results Available","Condition1","Enhanced Education","Improvement in A1C","18 Years to 85 Years   (Adult, Senior)","NIH","https://folder1//folder4"],["Evaluation of a Pilot","Completed","No Results Available","Condition1","Behavioral","Change in percent of total calories","10 Years to 19 Years   (Child, Adult)","Other","https://folder1//folder5"],["Self Management Skills","Completed","No Results Available","Condition1","Behavioral","Metabolic control","18 Years and older   (Adult, Senior)","Industry","https://folder1//folder6"]]
```

Each `list` withing the above `list of list` has `9` elements/columns. I also have a search string defined as below:

```
def fundingType = "NIH"
```

Now what I want to do is look for the presence of this string in the `8th` element/column of each list and if its present then store rest 8 elements in 8 different variables - `var1`,`var2`,....`var8`. How can I do this in `Groovy`?

Comment: Can you check the solution to see if that helps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to get it easily using `find` as shown below:

```
def fundingType = "NIH"
println rList.find{ fundingType == it[7] }
```

You can quickly try it online <kbd>[demo](https://ideone.com/UIiUMS)</kbd>​

Instead of 8 variables, you could change it as:

```
def result = rList.find{ fundingType == it[7] }
```

And use `result[0]`, `result[1]`...without using additional 8 variables.

Comment: Why bother with the `in` check first? Isn't the `fundingType==it[7]` good enough and more efficient?

Comment: @cfrick, thank you for the input. Initially I just had `in` only and later realized that OP specified position, so ended up adding `and` condition. Updated.

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
def rList = [["Using Patient Feedback","Completed","No Results Available","Condition1","Other","Phase I","18 Years and older   (Adult, Senior)","Other","https://folder1//folder2"],["The Effect of a Education ","Completed","No Results Available","Condition1","Behavioral","Glycemic Control","18 Years and older   (Adult, Senior)","Other","https://folder1//folder3"],["The Public Private Partnership","Completed","No Results Available","Condition1","Enhanced Education","Improvement in A1C","18 Years to 85 Years   (Adult, Senior)","NIH","https://folder1//folder4"],["Evaluation of a Pilot","Completed","No Results Available","Condition1","Behavioral","Change in percent of total calories","10 Years to 19 Years   (Child, Adult)","Other","https://folder1//folder5"],["Self Management Skills","Completed","No Results Available","Condition1","Behavioral","Metabolic control","18 Years and older   (Adult, Senior)","Industry","https://folder1//folder6"]]
def fundingType = "NIH"
def fundingColumnIndex = 7

def fundingRow = rList.find { it[fundingColumnIndex] == fundingType }
fundingRow.remove(fundingColumnIndex)
assert fundingRow.size() == 8
def (v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6, v7, v8) = fundingRow
[v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6, v7, v8].each { println(it) }
```

Output:

```
The Public Private Partnership
Completed
No Results Available
Condition1
Enhanced Education
Improvement in A1C
18 Years to 85 Years   (Adult, Senior)
https://folder1//folder4
```